# redirect http request for microsoft.com to a local server?

Tags: networking, http, redirection, hosts-file

I have been using host file to redirect required outgoing traffic to my localhost

normally i would just do something like this in the host file :

```
127.0.0.1 microsoft.com www.microsoft.com
```

but now that i need to redirect request made to microsoft.com towards my localhost I noticed that this method does not work for microsoft.com, i read few posts on StackExchange addressing the similar issue , but all i could find is how to block the request using firewall outbound rules, nothing provided a solution to redirect the request to local host

Is there any alternate method to redirect the outgoing http post request to a localhost if microsoft.com is destination url of the request ?

Answer (score 1):

Add microsoft.com to hosts file with local IP 127.0.0.1

c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

open it in admin mode

```
    127.0.0.1       microsoft.com
```

Comment: this doesnt work for microsoft.com , since windows os doesnt allow the host file redirects for its own domains